# $2\log |f(z)|-2\log |z|$ is harmonic function where $f$ is holomorphic in an annulus

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $U$ denote the open annulus $\{z\in \Bbb C:1<|z|<2\}$ and suppose $f:U\to U$ is a holomorphic bijection. I want to show that $u(z)=2\log |f(z)|-2\log |z|$ is a harmonic function on $U$.

Clearly harmonic is a local property, so it suffices to show that $u$ is harmonic at each point of $U$. Also a function is harmonic in an open set iff it is locally the real part of a holomorphic function. Thus I tried to show that $u$ is locally the real part of a holomorphic function. The definition of $u$ suggests to consider the function $f(z)/z$ (because $u(z)=2\log |f(z)/z|$, which is nonzero and holomorphic in $U$, and satisfies $1/2 \leq |f(z)/z|\leq 2$. But I have no idea then. Any hints?

Comment: Can you see why $2\log(|z|)$ is harmonic?  Now focus on $\log(u^2+v^2)$, where $f=u+iv$ and $u$ and $v$  satisfy the CRE and are harmonic.

Comment: This is trivial. (i) $\log|z|$ is harmonic in $\{z\ne0\}$, (ii) If $u$ is harmonic and $f$ is holomorphic then $u\circ f$ is harmonic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Let $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ where $u$ and $v$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations and are, therefore harmonic.

Now just show that

$$\left( \frac{\partial }{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)\left( \frac{\partial }{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right) \log(u^2(x,y)+v^2(x,y))=0$$